# React useState and setState not updating immediately

Tags: reactjs, use-state

When I press a key and try to display it on console, the previous value will be it's current value based on the console

```
import {useState } from "react";

const [username,setUsername] = useState("");

const onChangeUsername = (event) => {
    setUsername(event.target.value);
    console.log(username)
    Axios.post(hostServer+"user/guestCheck", {
        username:username
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}

<input required type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autoComplete="off"
onChange={onChangeUsername} ></input>
```

How can I get the real current value using this code?

Comment: It is because `useState` is asynchronous. https://dev.to/shareef/react-usestate-hook-is-asynchronous-1hia

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `event.target.value` but the usual approach is it use a `useEffect` that depends on the value of `username`

(*and as an additional improvement you could use `useCallback` for the change handler to avoid creating a new one on each keystroke*)

```js
import {useState, useCallback, useEffect} from "react";

const [username, setUsername] = useState("");


const onChangeUsername = useCallback((event) => {
  setUsername(event.target.value);
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(username);
  
  Axios.post(hostServer + "user/guestCheck", {
    username: username
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  });
}, [username]);
```

---

Keep in mind thought that this code will create a new request for each keystroke, which might be a bit aggressive/taxing for the backend. Perhaps you should debounce it a little.

Answer (score 1):

**Method1: Try posting the data to server from event.target.value**

```
import {useState } from "react";

const [username,setUsername] = useState("");

const onChangeUsername = (event) => {
    setUsername(event.target.value);
    console.log(username)
    Axios.post(hostServer+"user/guestCheck", {
        username:event.target.value
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}

<input required type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autoComplete="off" onChange = { onChangeUsername } > </input>
```

**Method2: Use useEffect hook that will post the data once the username is updated and component is re-rendered.**

```
import {useState } from "react";

const [username,setUsername] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
    Axios.post(hostServer+"user/guestCheck", {
        username:event.target.value
    }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}, [username])
const onChangeUsername = (event) => {
    setUsername(event.target.value);
    console.log(username);
}


<input required type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"`enter code here`autoComplete="off" onChange = { onChangeUsername } > </input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the effect() hook that will render according to your data change.

Here a demo https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-satoshi-xxyxf?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

useState and setState work asynchronous. So it's not update state immediately.
There are two way to solve your problem.

1. You can pass the value directly without saving in a state

   ```
   import {useState } from "react";
   const [username,setUsername] = useState("");
   const onChangeUsername = (event) => {
   setUsername(event.target.value);
   let userName =event.target.value; 
   console.log(username)
   Axios.post(hostServer+"user/guestCheck", {
     username:userName
   }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
   });
   }
   <input required type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" 
   autoComplete="off"
   onChange={onChangeUsername} ></input>
   ```
2. You can use in useEffect and pass username

   ```
   import {useState, useEffect } from "react";

   const [username,setUsername] = useState("");

   const onChangeUsername = (event) => {
   setUsername(event.target.value);
   console.log(username)
   }

    useEffect(() => {
      funcToCallApi()
       }, [username]);

      funcToCallApi() {
        console.log(username)

        Axios.post(hostServer+"user/guestCheck", {
        username:username
        }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        });
       }
   ```